# Using non persistent Http Cookies to deliver out of band data to the browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom, caching

Imagine that your web application maintains a hit counter for one or multiple pages and that it also aggressively caches those pages for anonymous visitors. This poses the problem that at least the hitcount would be out of date for those visitors because although the hitcounter is accurately maintained on the server even for those visitors, they would see the old cached page for a while.

What if the server would continue to serve them the cached page but would pass the updated counter in a non-persistent http cookie to be read by a piece of javascript in the page that would inject the updated counter into the DOM.

Opinions?

Comment: if someone has disabled cookies... will non-persistent cookies even come through?

Comment: Not sure. But even if they aren't the negative impact would be limited to seeing an outdated hit count right?

Comment: True, but only if your javascriptcode has a default value in it which is displayed if the cookie can't be found

Comment: The default value would be just the original content of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never going to keep track of the visitors in this manner. If you are aggressively caching pages, intermediate proxies and browsers are also going to cache your pages. And so the request may not even reach your server for you to track.

The best way to do so would be to use an approach similar to google analytics. When the page is loaded, send an AJAX request to the server. This ajax request would increment the current counter value on the server, and return the latest value. Then the client side could could show the value returned by the server using javascript.

This approach allows you to cache as aggressively as you want without losing the ability to keep track of your visitors.

Comment: Yeah I think thats probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the page programmatically via asp or php out the cache yourself and replace the hitcounter.

Comment: You mean apply some smart (and potentially very flawed) regex magic to the cached content?

Comment: regex seems a bit over the top. If the text which needs replacing is defined as such: %%COUNTER%%   then you can just do a simple search and replace.

Comment: But this will still put the burden on the server. Replacing a string should be lightning fast but its still work on the server.

Comment: if you do client side caching (specify in a header to cache the page) then the cookie will also not be updated. If you do server side caching then the overhead of a simple replace is nothing against retransmitting the page anyway.

Comment: Well, the page I'm talking about is pretty costly to render so the savings of just returning a pre-rendered string versus a full rendering pass is pretty significant. The reason I'm not working with cache headers is that I need to be able to invalidate the cache once the content changes.